# Sum of y coordinates of a closed curve in the plane

Tags: calculus, soft-question

Given a closed curve in the xy plane, then If i start from an initial point and walk along the curve returning finally to my starting point, if i want to measure how far i moved on the y-axis, then the answer needs to be zero. There is an other answer in reality, and it state the total amount of displacement on the y-axis.

E.g. For a circumference with center the origin, it is evident that if integrate the y-coordinate (i.e. Sinx) from 0 to $2\pi$  then the integral is 0. If I want the total displacement i have to integrate $|\sin x |$.

But for a generic curve , to obtain the same analytic formula which formalises the intuitive idea of "how much displacement ", how can i center my axes in a way that the integral of the y-coordinate becomes meaningful?

Comment: I think you're getting the two mixed up - displacement would be zero, since *displacement* means the distance from your starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l\in\mathbb R^2$ be a smooth curve with a differential $\vec ds$. Typically, we define *displacement* $\vec D$ as a path independent vector quantity.

$$\vec D=\int_ld\vec s$$

In Euclidian coordinates, we can look at the $y$ component of displacement independently.

$$D_y=\int_ldy$$

We can also define the *path length* $S$ as the integral of the magnitude of the differential.

$$S=\int_l|d\vec s|$$

To define a "path length in the $y$ direction" $S_y$, as you have, we can extend the analogy.

$$S_y=\int_l|dy|$$

We can think of $D_y$ as projecting the curve onto the $y$-axis, then finding the displacement. We can likewise think of $S_y$ as projecting the curve onto the $y$-axis, then finding the path length. It is of course dependent of your choice of coordinate system, but at least it is translation invariant.

To compute $S_y$ we can use a parameterization of the path $\vec \sigma:[a, b]\to l$, and differentiate its $y$-component.

$$S_y=\int_a^b\left|\frac{d\sigma_y}{dt}\right|dt$$

For a particular curve, this quantity will depend only on the choice of basis vector $\hat y$. We can define a more general "path length in a particular direction" which doesn't depend on coordinates:

$$S_{\vec v}=\int_l|d\vec s\cdot\vec v|=\int_a^b\left|\frac{d\vec\sigma}{dt}\cdot\vec v\right|dt$$

Comment: Thank you. And with this formalism, If i want to say that intuitively the sum of the y-coordinates needs to be zero for a closed curve, how can i? I mean , If i start at a height $y_0$ and run over the curve , i have to return at $y_0$ , and so i mean the height difference needs to be zero. How can one rigorously prove this?

Comment: Showing that the $y$ displacement is zero would just be the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. $$\oint_ldy=\int_a^bd\sigma_y=\sigma_y(b)-\sigma_y(a)$$ In the case of closed curves, $\sigma_y(a)=\sigma_y(b)$.